# Debugger is flagging code when 2 macros ran together

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with a section of code is being flagged by the debugger, but I can't figure out why.
Section 1 is copying a sheet and renaming it a cell value.  This section seems to work fine.
Section 2 is copying a set of cells then updating the formulas to read the new sheet.
If I run the 2 completely seperatly they both work, but if I run them together it fails and the debugger highlights the following line.
pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Resize(63, 1).Select
The code seems to be executing this part but it isn't moving onto the next line to replace.
I tried using a Master Macro to run them sequentially, but that had the same issue.  But if I ran Section 1, Then ran section 2 seperately after running Section 1, it works.  Does anyone know what I'm doing that is causing this not to work?

```
Sub Add_New_Location()

' Section 1
    Dim CellValue As String
    
    CellValue = Worksheets("Quantitative Metrics").Range("D68").Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("CT Input").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets("CT Input (2)").Name = CellValue
    Rows("2:16").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = CellValue
    
' Section 2
    Dim copysheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copysheet = Worksheets("Quantitative Metrics")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Quantitative Metrics")

    copysheet.Range("L1:T63").Copy

    pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial

    pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Resize(63, 1).Select

    
    Selection.Replace What:="CT Input", Replacement:=CellValue, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't select a range on a non-active sheet...

Comment: Run-time error '1004'  Select method of Range class failed

Comment: `pasteSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Resize(63, 1).Replace What:="CT Input", Replacement:=CellValue, ...`. No need to `Select` here.

Comment: @Tim, you seem to have been right.  I added to activate the PasteSheet and it seems to now work together.  Thank you

Comment: Adding `.Activate` is the shortcut that's inefficient and unnecessary. Instead, [avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in the first place, which is easily done by combining the last two code statements into one.